# How can I access obj from a list of student courses

Tags: c#

I've created a list of courses that students are enrolled in. However, I can't figure out how to access the objects from the list in the Main. Below, I've tried to get the Student-Id and pull the information from there, but it isn't working. I'm new to coding please help

```cs
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Text; using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace Jvstt_College
{
    class Admin 
    {
       ## 


 ## Dictionary<int, Student> studentList = new Dictionary<int, Student>();

        Dictionary<int, Professor> professorList = new Dictionary<int, Professor>();
        List<Course> courseList = new List<Course>();
        Dictionary<int, Student> studentCourses = new Dictionary<int, Student>();

        public Dictionary<int, Student> StudentList()
        {

            var Student1 = new Student() { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = " Jones", Password = "Test", EnrollmentId = 111111};
            var Student2 = new Student() { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = " Thomas", Password = "Grace", EnrollmentId = 101203 };
            var Student3 = new Student() { FirstName = "Jake", LastName = " Riley", Password = "SavedbyChrist1", EnrollmentId = 568903 };
            var Student4 = new Student() { FirstName = "Olivia", LastName = " Beckam", Password = "GodisGood", EnrollmentId = 951357 };
            var Student5 = new Student() { FirstName = "Myrai", LastName = " Bailey", Password = "ChildofGod", EnrollmentId = 741369 };
            var Student6 = new Student() { FirstName = "Majea", LastName = " Bailey", Password = "CoastLand", EnrollmentId = 852146 };

            studentList.Add(111111, Student1);
            studentList.Add(101203, Student2);
            studentList.Add(568903, Student3);
            studentList.Add(951357, Student4);
            studentList.Add(741369, Student5);
            studentList.Add(852146, Student6);
            return studentList;
        }
        public Dictionary<int, Professor> ProfessorList()
        {
            professorList.Add(654321, new Professor { FirstName = "Grace", LastName = "Riley", Password = "Gracey1983", EnrollmentId = 654321 });
          enter code here  professorList.Add(852963, new Professor { FirstName = "Liam",  LastName = "Beckam", Password = "Password", EnrollmentId = `enter code here`852963 });
            professorList.Add(359861, new Professor { FirstName = "Martha", LastName = "Hart", Password = "QwertYy00", EnrollmentId = 359861 });
            professorList.Add(612832, new Professor { FirstName = "George", LastName = "Washington", Password = "Kid$nExtD00r", EnrollmentId = 612832 });
            return professorList;

        }
        public List<Course> CourseList()
        {
            var Accounts = new Course() { CourseID = 101, CourseName = " Accounts " };
            var Bio_Psychology = new Course() { CourseID = 102, CourseName = " Bio_Psychology " };
            var Business = new Course() { CourseID = 103, CourseName = " Business " };
            var Chemistry = new Course() { CourseID = 104, CourseName = " Chemistry " };
            var CSWDCA = new Course() { CourseID = 105, CourseName = " Computer Science/Web Design/Cybersecurity Accounts" };
            var Psychology = new Course() { CourseID = 106, CourseName = " Psychology " };
            var Statistics = new Course() { CourseID = 107, CourseName = " Statistics " };
            var Advance_Math = new Course() { CourseID = 108, CourseName = "Advance Math" };

            courseList.Add(Accounts);
            courseList.Add(Bio_Psychology);
            courseList.Add(Business);
            courseList.Add(Chemistry);
            courseList.Add(CSWDCA);
            courseList.Add(Psychology);
            courseList.Add(Statistics);
            courseList.Add(Advance_Math);
            return courseList;
        }

        public Dictionary<int, Student> StudentEnrollments()
        {
            
           var Student1 = studentList[111111];
            {
                if(Student1.Courses == null)
                {
                    Student1.Courses = new List<Course>();
                    Student1.Courses?.Add(courseList[0]);
                    Student1.Courses?.Add(courseList[2]);
                    Student1.Courses?.Add(courseList[4]);
                }  
            }
            var Student2 = studentList[101203];
            {
                if(Student2.Courses == null)
                {
                    Student2.Courses = new List<Course>();

                    Student2.Courses?.Add(courseList[1]);
                    Student2.Courses?.Add(courseList[4]);
                    Student2.Courses?.Add(courseList[5]);
                    Student2.Courses?.Add(courseList[6]);
                    Student2.Courses?.Add(courseList[7]);
                }
            }

            var Student3 = studentList[568903];
            {
                if (Student3.Courses == null)
                {
                    Student3.Courses = new List<Course>();

                    Student3.Courses?.Add(courseList[1]);
                    Student3.Courses?.Add(courseList[4]);
                }
            }
            var Student4 = studentList[951357];
            {
                if (Student4.Courses == null)
                {
                    Student4.Courses = new List<Course>();

                    Student4.Courses?.Add(courseList[1]);
                    Student4.Courses?.Add(courseList[5]);
                    Student4.Courses?.Add(courseList[7]);
                }
            }

            var Student5 = studentList[741369];
            {
                if (Student5.Courses == null)
                {
                    Student5.Courses = new List<Course>();

                    Student5.Courses?.Add(courseList[0]);
                    Student5.Courses?.Add(courseList[2]);
                    Student5.Courses?.Add(courseList[3]);
                    Student5.Courses?.Add(courseList[6]);
                    Student5.Courses?.Add(courseList[7]);
                }
            }

            var Student6 = studentList[852146];
            {
                if (Student6.Courses == null)
                {
                    Student6.Courses = new List<Course>();

                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[0]);
                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[1]);
                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[2]);
                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[3]);
                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[4]);
                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[5]);
                    Student6.Courses?.Add(courseList[6]);
                }
            }

            studentCourses.Add(111111,Student1);
            studentCourses.Add(101203,Student2);
            studentCourses.Add(568903,Student3);
            studentCourses.Add(951357,Student4);
            studentCourses.Add(741369,Student5);
            studentCourses.Add(852146,Student6);
            return studentCourses;
        }
    }
}
                               }
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Include it as a [formatted code block](/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: Please provide more code so we know what is happening. Please use code blocks and not images. You will get a lot more help if you improve on that.

Comment: We also need to see the declaration of the variables used here. It is difficult to find a solution when the data types are unknown.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to coding, I hope this is better

Comment: Please can you mention what is Student ? What is studentList ? And why are you creating an array of StudentList with 111111 elements ?

Comment: Neither `studentList` nor `studentCourses` are declared here. You must pass `studentList as parameter to this method. Declare and create the dictionary inside the method.

Comment: _“it isn't working”_ is neither an error message nor a problem statement. Please read [ask].

Comment: @LYass the array wasn't created with elements of 111111. That's the key in the studentList from the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's declare the `Professor`, `Student` and `Course` classes. Since `Professor` and `Student` have similar properties and since they both are persons, it makes sense to derive them both from an abstract `Person` class. An abstract class cannot be instantiated.

```cs
abstract class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int EnrollmentId { get; set; }
}

class Professor : Person
{
}

class Student : Person
{
    public List<Course> Courses { get; } = new List<Course>();
}

class Course
{
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
}
```

In class `Student` I created the `Courses` list as read-only property and initialized it with a property initializer. This saves you from having to do something like `if (Student2.Courses == null) { Student2.Courses = new List<Course>(); ... }` later.

You have several method initializing lists and dictionaries. Those should declare and create the collections they return. Otherwise, if the collections are declared in a surrounding scope, the return statement would not be required and the responsibilities would not be clear. Add also, a dictionary is not a list. Since these methods do rely on instance fields anymore, we make them static (and simplify them):

```cs
// In class Admin
private static Dictionary<int, Student> CreateStudents()
{
    return new Dictionary<int, Student> {
        { 111111, new Student { FirstName = "Tom", LastName = " Jones", Password = "Test", EnrollmentId = 111111 } },
        { 101203, new Student { FirstName = "Mark", LastName = " Thomas", Password = "Grace", EnrollmentId = 101203 } },
        { 568903, new Student { FirstName = "Jake", LastName = " Riley", Password = "SavedbyChrist1", EnrollmentId = 568903 } },
        { 951357, new Student { FirstName = "Olivia", LastName = " Beckam", Password = "GodisGood", EnrollmentId = 951357 } },
        { 741369, new Student { FirstName = "Myrai", LastName = " Bailey", Password = "ChildofGod", EnrollmentId = 741369 } },
        { 852146, new Student { FirstName = "Majea", LastName = " Bailey", Password = "CoastLand", EnrollmentId = 852146 } }
    };
}

private static Dictionary<int, Professor> CreateProfessors()
{
    return new Dictionary<int, Professor> {
        { 654321, new Professor { FirstName = "Grace", LastName = "Riley", Password = "Gracey1983", EnrollmentId = 654321 } },
        { 852963, new Professor { FirstName = "Liam", LastName = "Beckam", Password = "Password", EnrollmentId = 852963 } },
        { 359861, new Professor { FirstName = "Martha", LastName = "Hart", Password = "QwertYy00", EnrollmentId = 359861 } },
        { 612832, new Professor { FirstName = "George", LastName = "Washington", Password = "Kid$nExtD00r", EnrollmentId = 612832 } }
    };

}

private static List<Course> CreateCourses()
{
    return new List<Course> {
        new Course { CourseID = 101, CourseName = "Accounts" },
        new Course { CourseID = 102, CourseName = "Bio_Psychology" },
        new Course { CourseID = 103, CourseName = "Business" },
        new Course { CourseID = 104, CourseName = "Chemistry" },
        new Course { CourseID = 105, CourseName = "Computer Science/Web Design/Cybersecurity Accounts" },
        new Course { CourseID = 106, CourseName = "Psychology" },
        new Course { CourseID = 107, CourseName = "Statistics" },
        new Course { CourseID = 108, CourseName = "Advance Math" }
    };
}
```

Now, we can declare and initialize the collections like this:

```cs
class Admin
{
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Student> students = CreateStudents();
    public readonly Dictionary<int, Professor> professors = CreateProfessors();
    public readonly List<Course> courses = CreateCourses();
    ...
}
```

I made them read-only. This only means that we cannot assign it another collection later. The collections themselves are still read/write.

We do not need another collection `studentCourses`, we can directly add the courses to the students in our existing `students` dictionary.

If we declare an instance method `EnrollStudents` in class `Admin`, then it can access the fields of this class.

```cs
public void EnrollStudents()
{
    Student student = students[111111];
    student.Courses.Add(courses[0]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[2]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[4]);

    student = students[101203]; // It is okay to reuse the student variable
    student.Courses.Add(courses[1]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[4]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[5]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[6]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[7]);

    student = students[568903];
    student.Courses.Add(courses[1]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[4]);

    student = students[951357];
    student.Courses.Add(courses[1]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[5]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[7]);

    student = students[741369];
    student.Courses.Add(courses[0]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[2]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[3]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[6]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[7]);

    student = students[852146];
    student.Courses.Add(courses[0]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[1]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[2]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[3]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[4]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[5]);
    student.Courses.Add(courses[6]);
}
```

Note that we do not have to return anything. Since classes are reference types, all the students in the original `students` dictionary have now been updated with courses. Of course we must call this method somewhere (probably in `Main`).

But we can simplify this method with a new helper method, because we have a lot of repetitions we can avoid:

```cs
private void AddStudentCourses(Student student, params int[] courseIndexes)
{
    foreach (int index in courseIndexes) {
        student.Courses.Add(courses[index]);
    }
}

public void EnrollStudents()
{
    AddStudentCourses(students[111111], 0, 2, 4);
    AddStudentCourses(students[101203], 1, 4, 5, 6, 7);
    AddStudentCourses(students[568903], 1, 4);
    AddStudentCourses(students[951357], 1, 5, 7);
    AddStudentCourses(students[741369], 0, 2, 3, 6, 7);
    AddStudentCourses(students[852146], 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
}
```

Test:

```cs
var admin = new Admin();
admin.EnrollStudents();

var orderedStudents = admin.students.Values
    .OrderBy(s => s.LastName)
    .ThenBy(s => s.FirstName);
foreach (var student in orderedStudents) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{student.LastName} {student.FirstName} ({student.EnrollmentId})");

    IOrderedEnumerable<Course> orderedCourses = student.Courses.OrderBy(c => c.CourseName);
    foreach (var course in orderedCourses) {
        Console.WriteLine($"    {course.CourseName} ({course.CourseID})");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Prints

```
 Bailey Majea (852146)
    Accounts (101)
    Bio_Psychology (102)
    Business (103)
    Chemistry (104)
    Computer Science/Web Design/Cybersecurity Accounts (105)
    Psychology (106)
    Statistics (107)

 Bailey Myrai (741369)
    Accounts (101)
    Advance Math (108)
    Business (103)
    Chemistry (104)
    Statistics (107)

 Beckam Olivia (951357)
    Advance Math (108)
    Bio_Psychology (102)
    Psychology (106)

 Jones Tom (111111)
    Accounts (101)
    Business (103)
    Computer Science/Web Design/Cybersecurity Accounts (105)

 Riley Jake (568903)
    Bio_Psychology (102)
    Computer Science/Web Design/Cybersecurity Accounts (105)

 Thomas Mark (101203)
    Advance Math (108)
    Bio_Psychology (102)
    Computer Science/Web Design/Cybersecurity Accounts (105)
    Psychology (106)
    Statistics (107)
```

Comment: Thank you so much... I pray that you have an amazing day